# Webdav with LDAP configuration

Tags: 2013, configuration, webdav, ldap

I am using Tridion 2013 SP1 and want to know what are configuration require for using WebDAV with LDAP authentication?

Comment: http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-14E44838-51AE-4D5F-836C-4EFF2C438648

Comment: As per the given link if I make same IIS authentication settings in the webdav/ folder as same as for the Web site itself. I am getting "Internal server error" and in the event viewer I can see the below error:  "Access is denied for the user <<Directory Service Name>>\mtsuser  Component: Tridion.ContentManager.WebDav
Errorcode: 0
User: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE

Answer (score 2):

[Online docs](http://docs.sdl.com/) would appear to be your friend :)

[Configuring WebDAV Connector for LDAP authentication or single sign-on](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-14E44838-51AE-4D5F-836C-4EFF2C438648)

> No specific steps are needed to make use LDAP or SSO authentication
>   work if you use WebDAV (if both are properly set up, as documented),
>   as long as you ensure that your IIS authentication settings in the
>   `webdav/` folder are the same as for the Web site itself.

[Configuring LDAP](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-3473B938-77E4-4EC4-BAEE-16C2FB43083A)

Comment: Thanks David for sharing the link but I think HTTPS is require to use LDAP with WebDAV. Can you please confirm if this is mandatory? Configuring WebDAV Connector authentication under Configuring WebDAV Connector

Comment: This appears to be a limitation of the Windows WebDAV client. If you read through the instructions for configuring LDAP or SSO you find this text: "To use LDAP or single sign-on (SSO) to authenticate users in Content Manager, you must allow Basic authentication. A Windows WebDAV client refuses to use Basic authentication over a non-secure (non-HTTPS) connection. As a result, to use LDAP or SSO, you must use HTTPS."